# ELB and Cloudfront API parameters being ignored

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two endpoints on my Elastic Beanstalk application:

- [Cloudfront API Link 1](https://api.erc-hackney.com/sermon?limit=30)
- [ELB API Link 2](http://erchackney-env.yrpkxk2pty.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/sermon?limit=30)

First of which I've set up Cloudfront and linked to my URL.
The second is where my Elastic Beanstalk application is set up?

Why are the API parameters being registered on the latter.... and being ignored on the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudfront strips the query string by default so it basically making request without query string to the beanstalk, you need to whitelist the particular query string or ALL to make it work like beanstalk link.

Comment: Relevant docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html

Comment: Thanks James. I have done this and it works, but for some reason it seems like there is a delay to sync the Cloudfront API result with the ELB API result. Any reason why this is the case?

Comment: It may be because of caching, you want to see of you're see HIT from CloudFront for the request which is not sync, the X-Cache header is present in the response header.